# Mongoose: Cast to date failed for value when updating a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use Mongoose in my project and in one of the schemas I use Date field, like this:

```
reservationDay: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
}
```

I can create document with this field without a problem. And when I console.log this date after it has been created I get:

```
reservationDay:  Thu Nov 20 2014 04:45:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

However, there is a problem when I try tu update this document (even without changing reservationDay field). Here is the error message I get:

```
name: 'CastError',
  message: 'Cast to date failed for value "20/11/2014 04:11" at path "reservationDay"' } CastError: Cast to date failed for value "20/11/2014 04:11" at path "reservationDay"
```

Here is how I update this document on server side:

```
Reservation.findOne({ _id: id }).exec(function(err, reservation) {
                        if (err) {
                            //handle
                        }
                        if (!reservation) {
                            //handle
                        }
                        reservation = extend(reservation, req.body);
                        reservation.save(function(err, updatedReservation) {
                            if (err) {
                                //handle
                            }
                            return res.json(reservation);
                        });
                    });
```

and the date is not changed in the req.body.

Any ideas what might cause this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

`"20/11/2014 04:11"` is an invalid ISODate format. Somewhere you are converting reservationDate into a string of an invalid format. You need to convert it to a valid ISODate format (month before day):

```
new Date("11/20/2014 04:11") // Thu Nov 20 2014 04:11:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
new Date("2014/11/20 04:11") // Thu Nov 20 2014 04:11:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
new Date("20/11/2014 04:11") // Invalid Date
```

for easy manipulation of date formats, I'd recommend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 2):

**Convert date to MongoDB ISODate format in JavaScript using Moment JS**

MongoDB uses ISODate as their primary date type. If you want to insert a date object into a MongoDB collection, you can use the **Date()** shell method.

You can specify a particular date by passing an ISO-8601 date string with a year within the inclusive range 0 through 9999 to the **new Date()** constructor or the ISODate() function. These functions accept the following formats:

- **new Date(`"<YYYY-mm-dd>"`)** returns the ISODate with the specified date.
- **new Date(`"<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss>"`)** specifies the datetime in the client’s local timezone and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.
- **new Date(`"<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ>"`)** specifies the datetime in UTC and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.
- new Date() specifies the datetime as milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970), and returns the resulting ISODate instance.

If you are writing code in JavaScript and if you want to pass a JavaScript date object and use it with MongoDB client, the first thing you do is convert JavaScript date to MongoDB date format (ISODate). Here’s how you do it.

```
    var today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T00:00:00.000Z]');
    console.log("Next day -- " + (reqDate.getDate() + 1))
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(reqDate.getDate() + 1);
    var tomorrow = moment(d).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T00:00:00.000Z]');
```

**You can pass today and tomorrow object to MongoDB queries with new Date() shell method.**

```
  MongoClient.connect(con, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err
    db.collection('orders').find({ "order_id": store_id, "orderDate": {     
       "$gte": new Date(today), "$lt": new Date(tomorrow)}
     }).toArray(function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (err) throw err
          res.send(result);
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to update one point from my mistake.

***check if you have missed leading zero for a single digit time.***

**"2017-01-01T8:00:00" is invalid** and will give the mentioned error.

**"2017-01-01T08:00:00" is valid**

Answer (score 0):

All of the above solutions didnt work for me, instead this worked:
I updated the function containing the updation code and added Date manually to the mongo object, in my case it was user with lastLogin so the code looked something like this

```
user.lastLogin = Date.now();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I get this error since I tried to `find` with the operator `$gt` with parenthesis which not really needed.

Like this:
`find({ date: { $gt: {fromDate} } });`

The fix was:
`find({ date: { $gt: fromDate } });`