# Mongoose: Failed to cast ISO date

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a date:

> 2016-04-13T09:57:21-04

Unless I am incorrect, this is a [valid ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but I am getting cast errors with Mongoose:

> "Cast to date failed for value \"2016-04-13T09:57:21-04\" at path \"timestamp\""

I looked over some other [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827584/mongoose-cast-to-date-failed-for-value-when-updating-a-document), and from my understanding, valid ISO formats should work.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert this string to Date object first. Mongoose expects Date instead of string.

Comment: Is this something that we always need to do in Node? The object is coming in from a scala app as a datetime

Comment: Yup! Its because the JSON has it as a string literal. Thanks!